# Angular FormGroup controls property not updated when removing controls

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

I have a custom validator directive which takes in an angular `FormGroup`. The `controls` property mainly updates as expected, but it seems to struggle with controls being removed from the `FormGroup`. It's my first time using a `FormGroup` so I don't know if I've implemented it incorrectly.

The basic structure of my page is that the user can select multiple values from a dropdown, and they are added to a table which contains an input element. Everything in this table (i.e. one row per selected value) is in the same `FormGroup`. If I add 3 rows to the table, then `group.controls` (correctly) contains `name0`, `name1` and `name2`. However, if I then remove the 2nd then 3rd selections, then `group.controls` contains `name0` (correct) and `name2` (incorrect).

This is the basic structure of the form:

```
<form #modelsForm="ngForm">

    <div class="form-group" ngModelGroup="testModelGroup" #componentModelsFormGroup="ngModelGroup" [appFnValidate]="testValidator">
        <ng-select [items]="models" bindLabel="name" name="models" #modelSelection="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selectedModels" (add)="selectModel($event)" (remove)="deselectModel($event)" (clear)="deselectAll()">
    </ng-select>

    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-bordered text-nowrap no-margin">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let componentModel of component.componentModels; let rowNo = index">
                <td>
                    {{componentModel.modelName}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="form-control" required #componentModelNameValue="ngModel" [name]="'name' + rowNo" [(ngModel)]="componentModel.name" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>

</form>
```

The `[appFnValidate]="testValidator"` code currently just logs out to the console which controls the `FormGroup` contains.

I've made a stackblitz which allows reproduction. If you open the dev console you'll be able to see the logging from the validator.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-group-not-updating

Any ideas what I need to do to make the `FormGroup` `controls` property update correctly when removing controls from the group?

Comment: You have no FormGroup -it's used in ReactiveForm-, just [(ngModel)] -used in Template Form-

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for your comment, I was a bit confused as I was trying to read around the topic. The `testValidator` method takes in a `FormGroup` as a parameter, so where's that coming from? I assumed it was something to do with the `ngModelGroup` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realised the root cause of this bug just as I was finishing formatting the question, so I thought I might as well still post it in the hope it benefits someone else in the future!

This issue was caused by the name of the input control within the table, which was set like this: `[name]="'name' + rowNo"` where `rowNo` came from the `*ngFor="let componentModel of component.componentModels; let rowNo = index"`.

However, as rows are deleted, unless they're the last row, the deletion changes the index of the other rows. This seems to prevent angular from keeping track of everything correctly (presumably because the name gets reused - i.e. if I delete the control named `name0` then a different control will be renamed to `name0`).

The fix was very simple, just use a better unique identifier for each row in the table! I used `componentModel.modelId` as I know that's guaranteed to be unique in my scenario. This was the only code which needed changing. The `tr` tag thus became:

```
<tr *ngFor="let componentModel of component.componentModels">
    <td>
        {{componentModel.modelName}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" required #componentModelNameValue="ngModel" [name]="'name' + componentModel.modelId" [(ngModel)]="componentModel.name" />
    </td>
</tr>
```